# View Pager overlapping footer

Tags: android

I am using View pager and footer in relative layout.but view pager size out of the screen because I used scroll view .when I scrolling view pager up to down then its overlapping footer.so how can solve this problem 
here is the code `

```
{
             <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

             <RelativeLayout 
               xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
               android:id="@+id/rl_contentDetail"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="@color/white">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <include
            android:id="@+id/footerId_slider"
            layout="@layout/footer"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- for show footer -->

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll_top"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
            android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
            android:scrollbars="none" >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:orientation="vertical">

               <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl_top"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/headerView_pager_gallery_slider"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/galleryviewpager_height"
                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ibLeft"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/left"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ibRight"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/right"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />
            </RelativeLayout>

                <include
                    layout="@layout/photogallery_sliding_row"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/rl_top"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" />
                </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added layout_above in the scroll view and also set the height to match_parent. It will let the scroll view be above the footer. Try this.

```
<ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll_top"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
            android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
            android:scrollbars="none" 
            android:layout_above="@+id/footer">
```